# Increment a database value after printing a report

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a database table with just one column, invoiceNumber. This is displayed on a Crystal Report to show the unique number of the report (as it's an invoice).

At the moment, for all of the reports, when viewing them in vb.net, the number being displayed is 1, because that's what the value in the database column is.

What I want to know is, how can I increment the number after and only after the report has been printed (if they cancel the print job it doesn't increment, for example).

I know this is usually simple, it would use SQL after the print code on the button press, however, in the project, I am using a `CrystalReportViewer` so printing isn't done on a button click, and I don't think the printing in a `CrystalReportViewer` can be programmed separately?

So how and where do I code the value in the database table to incremement by 1 after the report has printed? Is this even possible?

Comment: You have to consider printer jams and coffee spills.  It might be better to program an override.  Then you can increment on report launch...  Unless you expect many occurrences where a report would be viewed and not printed. In that case you might want a confirmation button press after the report is displayed / closed.

Comment: @JoeC I am considering incrementing it on report launch in honesty. I could then have a message box asking if they want to exit without printing. But how would I make this work? I'd need to somehow find a way of telling it whether or not it has been printed... How would this be done?

Comment: Are you using the windows forms report viewer?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227057(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @JoeC yes, that's what I'm using on the report form, that's what handles all of the printing etc, rather than me coding it all individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a flag which is set on acknowledgement after print is successful.

In another function you can check if flag is set and increment the flag accordingly.

Comment: How do you mean? I'm not familiar with flags

Comment: any boolean variable to hold a value as 1 for printed and 0 for not printed

Comment: And this would be declared and set where?

Comment: You may declare it at initiation of your code, and set it at acknowledgement you receive after printing.

Comment: This isn't possible, thinking about it, as some invoices may be emailed, rather than printed, and also the same report form displays non-invoice reports, so if they were printed, it would incorrectly increment the value in the database

Comment: Are you saying you have no way of receiving distinct acknowledgement for both these activities???

Comment: Well, no, there's no way in the code of telling whether it was an invoice or a different type of report that was opened, or whether or not it was emailed

Comment: well, you have to change requirement then. you may ask recipient of mail to send acknowledgement in mail, based on which you can develop another piece of code and update database.

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest using a confirmation button for the user to confirm they have printed it OK.  No other way to be sure it came out of the printer without jams, smudges, creased paper etc etc

Pseudocode

```
  EventHandlerWhichTriggersReportCreation

   Call code to initiate and load CrystalReportViewer
   Display dialog/prompt asking user if all printed  OK
   If all OK, increment counter
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the code would have to go in the subroutine where the print is processed, but there is no code for this as it's all done using a `CrystalReportViewer`

Comment: Is there literally no event which is fired or code o run the report or a Form_Load function or anything?.  I have added some pseudocode above.